# cant type text inside the text box

Tags: html, css

```js
  test() {
    console.log('Search button clicked!!!');
  }
```

```css
.container-4{
//   overflow: hidden;
//   width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 270px; 
   left: 300px; 
   width: 100%; 
   // z-index: 9;
}

.container-4 input#search{
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #045697;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  color: #65737e;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top:15px;
//    z-index: 10;
}

.container-4 button.icon{
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 
  border: 2px solid #045697;
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #045697;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-top:15px;
 
  -webkit-transition: all .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .55s ease;
//   -o-transition: all .55s ease;
  transition: all .55s ease;
}

.container-4 input#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #65737e;
}
 
.container-4 input#search:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #65737e;  
}
 
.container-4 input#search::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #65737e;  
}
 
.container-4 input#search:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #65737e;  
}

.container-4 button.icon, .container-4:active button.icon, .container-4:focus button.icon{
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -50px;
    background: white;
  }
 
  .container-4 button.icon:hover{
    background: white;
  }

.container-4{

   left: 400px; 
}

.container-4{

    left: 30px; 
    top: 130px; 

}

.container-4{

    left: 5px; 
    top: 60px; 

}

.container-4 input#search{
    width:415px;
}

.container-4 input#search{
    width:365px;
}

.container-4 input#search{
    width:310px;
    font-size:13px!important;
}

.container-4{

    left: 5px; 
    top: 50px; 

}

.container-4{

    left: 5px; 
    top: 40px; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-4">
    <input class="form-control searchbar" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Discover more about any career you like" />
    <button (click)="test()" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    
  </div>
```

I'am not able to type text inside the textbox in chrome browser but when i navigate from other page it works. The same code works fine on IE and sometimes in firefox.

Here is my HTML code:----------------------------------------------------------

```
 <div class="container-4">
    <input class="form-control searchbar" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Discover more about any career you like" />
    <button (click)="test()" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
```

here is my css:-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
.container-4{
//   overflow: hidden;
//   width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 270px; 
   left: 300px; 
   width: 100%; 
   // z-index: 9;
}

.container-4 input#search{
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #045697;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  color: #65737e;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top:15px;
//    z-index: 10;
}

.container-4 button.icon{
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

  border: 2px solid #045697;
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #045697;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-top:15px;

  -webkit-transition: all .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .55s ease;
//   -o-transition: all .55s ease;
  transition: all .55s ease;
}

.container-4 input#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #65737e;
}

.container-4 input#search:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #65737e;  
}

.container-4 input#search::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #65737e;  
}

.container-4 input#search:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #65737e;  
}

.container-4 button.icon, .container-4:active button.icon, .container-4:focus button.icon{
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -50px;
    background: white;
  }

  .container-4 button.icon:hover{
    background: white;
  }

.container-4{

   left: 400px; 
}

.container-4{

    left: 30px; 
    top: 130px; 

}

.container-4{

    left: 5px; 
    top: 60px; 

}

.container-4 input#search{
    width:415px;
}

.container-4 input#search{
    width:365px;
}

.container-4 input#search{
    width:310px;
    font-size:13px!important;
}

.container-4{

    left: 5px; 
    top: 50px; 

}

.container-4{

    left: 5px; 
    top: 40px; 
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code inside a fiddle/snippet?

Comment: `button (click)="test()"` is not valid HTML

Comment: i'am working on angular 2 where i have given a click function to the button

Comment: i have added the snippet sir

Comment: It's working fine in chrome I can type text there in the input field.

Comment: It's working fine in chrome and firefox. On which platform or browser are you having the issue?

Comment: there is no problem with this snippet , can you provide your url

Comment: here is my url:-  http://mentoriaweb.azurewebsites.net/#/app/home

Comment: if you scroll down you will see a search bar.. i cant type text inside it.

Comment: i force loaded( ctrl + f5 ) my browser then it started working.

Comment: This type of problem normally occurs when a div remains open.

Comment: I just now found out that when the page is loading textbox works but when page gets fully loaded it stops working.